# Oracle Insert statement hangs

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a job that loads the data into table A and it’s just 32K records. The `select` query inside the `insert` statement is executing in 20 seconds, but looks like we are not able to insert the data into this table and it hangs.

Any possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Did you check if any other session has lock on that table?

Comment: I am able to issue the truncate statement on this table successfully and only insert hangs.

Comment: @beckham do you have any INSERT trigger for that table. Or if this table has a foreign key and not matching with referencing table?

Comment: Hello, there are no insert triggers on this table. I have just dropped the table and recreated again and it’s still an issue.. I didn’t do any triggers..

Comment: Check `select * from dba_resumable;` for any suspended sessions.  That might tell you if there's a space issue.  Maybe the user has exceeded their tablespace quota, the tablespace is full, the ASM diskgroup is full, etc.

Comment: Hi Jon, there was no table space issue. We have loaded lot of other tables in the same schema successfully.

Comment: As a first step, check `v$session` during the load and see if it is blocked (`BLOCKING_SESSION`, `BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS`, `LOCKWAIT `) and what the current wait is (`STATE`, `WAIT_CLASS`, `EVENT`).

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Do you have access to sys? You can run the following there to see what long operations are running in YOUR_SCHEMA.   

`SELECT * FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS WHERE SID IN (SELECT SID FROM V$SESSION WHERE USERNAME IN ('$YOUR_SCHEMA$') AND STATUS='ACTIVE') ORDER BY START_TIME;`   

Also are you using any IDE? Can you generate the execution plan?

Comment: Just an update. We ran the stats on the tables and i am able to successfully run the job.   I am still confused, thr job is going into hang state before the stats were updated, but the job is successfully after the completion of stats update.. :( ... any way i can disable to stats on the tables in the query while running?..

Comment: Hi Sergey - i dont have access to sys. I am using sql developer..Can disabling index using No Index hint helps if the stats are not updated correctly?..

Comment: You don't need SYS to query v$session or v$session_longops.

Comment: If gathering stats fixed the issue then the problem was poor performance not hanging.

Comment: If you are interested in getting to root cause, I would: 1. Get a SQL Monitor report of the good execution. 2 Delete the stats and provided a SQL Monitor report of the bad execution

Comment: I'm very late, but we experienced this similar issue and the cause was uncommitted changes in Oracle. My situation was practically similar to that of OP. My team and I have Oracle DB and use SQL Developer. I had a table that we're inserting into with data from a select statement. My select statement worked and insert statement to other tables worked, but not to this one specific table. Then, something that I realized a little while back was, you have to manually commit your changes with SQL Developer (except when you run certain commands that causes an auto-commit,...

Comment: ...e.g. granting table permissions). As soon as I committed my changes in SQL Developer, the insert statement stopped hanging.